# How to use given-name entity in fulfillment in google actions?

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google

I have been trying to make an action for google which recognises names.But whenever I try to pass $given-name entity as a parameter for an intent in the fulfillment it shows me an error telling that the parameter cannot contain '-' this character.This is the code which I am using.I am entirely new in this field.Can someone please tell me where am i making a mistake?

```
app.intent('Recognize Name',(conv,{given-name},{date})=>{

conv.end(`Name:${name},Date:${date}`);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer,I realized that i need to take  parameters object as a single argument in the app.intent() and later extract them one by one.

Comment: Yes, that's because the `app.intent` callback sends `parameters` as an argument, and you can destructure that argument into its separated properties.